# Unexpected crash while drawing view in android

Tags: android, exception, view, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I am writing music player app and I have reused single fragment for showing recycler view for classification of music in by title, by artist, by album and by genre.

I used this library https://github.com/FutureMind/recycler-fast-scroll to fast scroll section wise. Library is working fine in music my title, by artist and by album. BUt app force closed with excption when I try to switch to genre tab. Code for all 4 fragments is exactly same. 
In trace log, there is no trace of my code and I am unable to figure out where should I look in my code to solve this issue. Attaching trace log here , any help is appreciated.

```
12-10 19:09:08.204 16317-16317/com.bhandari.player.music.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bhandari.player.music.musicplayer, PID: 16317
Theme: themes:{}
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
   at com.futuremind.recyclerviewfastscroll.FastScroller.initHandleMovement(FastScroller.java:186)
   at com.futuremind.recyclerviewfastscroll.FastScroller.onLayout(FastScroller.java:162)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1799)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1142)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:836)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:850)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1142)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:836)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:850)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2934)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2179)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1939)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at andro
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No worries, solved it myself.
It was causing because of other tab which I created for showing folders. I used different fragment for that and forgot to initialize scroller to that.